# Remember Video Playback Last Position Jquery ajax PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Hi Everyone is there any **Php/Javascript/Ajax** code that can auto store **video last position** into database (like Youtube) or code can store video time after every one minute than visitors can **resume** video from that time please tell me if there is any code i dont want to use any plugin for this i am learning php,javascript,ajax so please tell me basic level code if there is

Answer (score 5):

Here's an example how could you store video time at regular intervals.

```js
const video = document.querySelector("video");
const videoId = video.src;
let intervalHandle = null;


video.addEventListener("play", (event) => {
  intervalHandle = setInterval(() => {
    savePosition(videoId, video.currentTime);
  }, 5000)
})

video.addEventListener("pause", (event) => {
  clearInterval(intervalHandle);
})

const getPosition = (videoId) => {
  // fetch(url) ...
  const defaultPosition = {
    videoId,
    position: 0
  }

  try {
    return localStorage.getItem("position") || defaultPosition;
  } catch (error) {

  }

  return defaultPosition;
}

const savePosition = (videoId, position) => {
  // fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: {videoId, position}}) ...
  try {
    localStorage.setItem("position", JSON.stringify({
      videoId,
      position
    }));
  } catch (error) {}
}

const result = getPosition(videoId);

video.currentTime = result.position;
```

```html
<video id="video" width="320" height="240" controls>

 <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```